# Is it allowed to send location datas via silent Push Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Does Apple allow to send location datas via Push Notification ?

For Example if I have a tracker that send location datas on server. Then server send silent Push Notifications in order to use it on an iOS app. With a payload like:

```
{
   "aps" : {
       "content-available" : 1
   },
   "longitude" : 7.770526,
   "latitude" : 52.032184,
}
```

Is it conform to apple guideline ? Because it exposes possible sensitive datas.

Comment: yes, you can send this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the data, but there is no guarantee when it arrives and when it is processed.

The data isn't *very* exposed because it will be encrypted. But it would be better if your app asked the server for the data.